# How can I speed up rendering of surface plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to generate surface plots in Python using `matplotlib` with around 100x100 points. I'm using the code below just to test it out:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

plt.show()
```

It all works fine, except for the fact that rotating the plot is very slow - the view changes around once per second, which is less than ideal. Using a wireframe plot instead of a surface plot gives acceptable performance, but it makes the data harder to see and means a colourmap can't be used. (Turning off anti-aliasing actually makes little difference.)

Is there anything I can do to speed it up, even if it's only a little?

Comment: Matplotlib really isn't meant to do 3D rendering of complex surfaces.  (It actually isn't handling occulsion at all, for example.)  Try `mayavi.mlab.surf(x, y, z)` instead.

Comment: I did have a look at that, but I'd like to create a GUI using Tkinter and from what I've seen it doesn't look like it's possible - I could be wrong though, I'm a novice when it comes to any kind of graphical stuff.